# Реализовать один-к-одному Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть 2 класса, хочу соединить связью один-к-одному

```
public class Profession : Model
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Test MainTest { get; set; }
    ...
}
public class Test
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Profession")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

     ...

    public Profession Profession { get; set; }
}
```

Выдает ошибку при компиляции:

> "The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Id' on type 'Test' is not valid.
>   The navigation property 'Profession' was not found on the dependent
>   type 'Test'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property
>   name."

Comment: Смотри тут  http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил что связь будет ноль или один к нулю или одному, сделал уникальные ключи и подключил

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<Profession>()
    .HasOptional(o => o.MainTest)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal()
    .Map(o => o.MapKey("ProfId"));

    modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
                .HasOptional(o => o.Profession)
                .WithOptionalPrincipal()
                .Map(o => o.MapKey("TestId"));

}
```